# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "perro"?

Tags: etimología, animales

En el DLE no se indica nada sobre la etimología de [**perro**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SihVF3L), que por otro lado no parece tener relación con su equivalente en latin (*canis*), griego (*kyōn*), francés (*chien*), inglés (*dog, hound*), alemán (*Hund*), etc.

[**Etymonline**](https://www.etymonline.com/classic/search?q=dog) indica que su orígen es desconocido, quizás ibero, sin más datos.

En el diccionario de Covarrubias se indica que procede del griego ***pyr*** (fuego), dato que es recogido después en el [Diccionario de Autoridades](http://web.frl.es/DA.html), que añade "Otros quieren se dixesse à ***rodendo pede***."

¿Existe alguna otra etimología, o más datos que avalen alguna de las que he encontrado?

**EDICION**

Como complemento a la respuesta de @Charlie, en [**Wiktionary**](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/perro) encuentro:

> La completa carencia de cognados en otras lenguas, así como su tardía aparición hacia mediados del siglo XII, hacen **improbable un étimo prerromano**; Coromines apunta como más plausible un origen expresivo en la interjección usada para llamar al animal, u onomatopéyica de su gruñido. Viejas teorías que lo relacionaban con el latín petra o, como en la fantasiosa entrada del DRAE de 1737, con el griego antiguo πῦρ (pỹr), carecen por entero de fundamento. **Más verosímil es la teoría de que la palabra es de origen gitano**

Comment: Aquí otra teoría: http://www.academia.edu/13000744/PERRO._Origen_etimol%C3%B3gico_fijado_por_Enrique_Cabrejas

Comment: @walen parece que sí es el mismo, no sé como de fiables serán sus investigaciones pero me pareció interesante mencionarlo por si se puede sacar algo de ahí

Answer (score 5):

Te apunto aquí lo que dice Joan Corominas en su diccionario etimológico abreviado:

> **PERRO,** 1136. Vocablo exclusivo del castellano, que en la Edad Media solo se emplea como término peyorativo y popular, frente a *can*, vocablo noble y tradicional. Origen incierto. Probablemente palabra de creación expresiva, quizá fundada en la voz *prrr, brrr*, con que los pastores incitan al perro, empleándola especialmente para que haga mover el ganado y para que este obedezca al perro. Compárese el gallego *apurrar* 'azuzar a los perros'. Son imposibles las etimologías ibéricas y célticas que se han propuesto.

Por otra parte, parece que *perro* es de esas palabras cuya etimología ha ido variando a lo largo de los tiempos:

- 1884: ¿Del zendo *vehrka*, lobo?
- 1899: ¿Del b. lat. *canis petronius*, perro de ganado; del lat. *petro*, carnero?
- 1914: Del lat. *petro*, rústico, con alusión a *canis petronius*, perro que caza por las asperezas de los montes.
- 1925: Sin etimología, y así hasta...
- 1970: Del grito *perr*, con que el pastor excita a las ovejas y al perro, así hasta...
- 1992: De origen incierto.
- 2001: Sin etimología, y así hasta hoy.

Es decir, que durante unos años la RAE le dio credibilidad a la investigación de Corominas, pero en los últimos años se ve que ya no lo tienen tan claro.

De los textos más antiguos que he encontrado que usan la palabra, mencionar este del siglo XII:

> *Qui mactaret perro qui lobos matat aut carnem escodire ad lupu pectet de decem menkales aiuso quantum iuraret su domno que ualebat.*
>
> Anónimo, "Fuero de Valfermoso de las Monjas", 1189 (España).