# ¿Por qué se dejó de usar "can", desplazada por "perro", y se convirtió prácticamente en un cultismo?

Tags: etimología, historia, animales

Para designar al mismo animal tenemos la palabra [**perro**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SihVF3L) y la de origen latino [**can**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=71dxXgr).

El [Diccionario de Autoridades](http://web.frl.es/DA.html) recoge (negritas mís)

> CAN. s. m. Lo mismo que Perro. Es voz antigua, que **solo se conserva en Astúrias, Galícia, y algunas otras partes, y entre los Poetas**. En todos los libros antíguos es común, porque se conocía poco la voz Perro.

En mi experiencia, hoy día apenas se utiliza la palabra **can** aislada, y solo pervive en compuestos y derivados, generalmente antiguos y más o menos cultos, como [caniculario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=78zdpbi), [canódromo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7A0q8Cn), [cancerbero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=74CNyHN), [canino](http://dle.rae.es/?id=79UjoUa), [cánido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=790SXci), etc.

¿Por qué se produjo este desplazamiento?
¿Es correcta la hipótesis de Corominas en la entrada de **perro**:

> Si la palabra *perro* pudo ganar terreno y acabó por eliminar el vocablo tradicional, se debió en buena parte a la falta de un femenino y un díminutivo correspondientes a *can*, que obligaba a servirse de *perra* y *perriello* ...

Comment: interesante pregunta, sobre todo por que nadie esta seguro del origen de la palabra perro, tal vez sea de origen gitano, tal vez sea de un origen aun mas antiguo.  sobre todo teniendo en cuenta que perro y hombre han sido amigos desde antes del origen de lo que la historia puede contar. tal vez un misterio perdido en alejandría

Answer (score 3):

No sé si hay un porqué - este fenómeno ha ocurrido muchas veces con otras palabras por razones obscuras, ej. [*caballa → yegua*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18659/18348), [*vulpeja → zorro*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26494/18348), [*siniestra → izquierda*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23081/18348) etc.

No obstante, la palabra para un 'perro' ha sido reemplazada en otras varias lenguas indoeuropeas<sup>1</sup>:

- `español` can → perro
- `catalán` ca → gos
- `irlandés` cú → madra
- `inglés` hound → dog
- `griego` κυων (*kuōn*) → σκύλος (*skýlos*)

Y podemos examinar las situaciones en eso:

#### Etimología

En el catalán, la palabra *ca* ha sido reemplazado por *gos*<sup>2</sup>, una palabra cuyo origen probablemente sea la onomatopeya de la voz con la que se suele llamar el perro<sup>3</sup>.

Esto es una origen similar de [la propuesta de *perro*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26679/18348):

> Origen incierto. Probablemente palabra de creación expresiva, quizá fundada en la voz *prrr, brrr,* con que los pastores incitan al perro, empleándola especialmente para que haga mover el ganado y para que este obedezca al perro. Compárese el gallego apurrar 'azuzar a los perros'.
>
> - *Breve diccionario etimológico de la lengua castellana*, Joan Coromines

Y también la origen de su sinónimo [*chucho*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=91vbETk):

> De la interjección *chuch*, con que se llama al perro para que acuda.

#### Motivo de difusión

El inglés *dog* viene del inglés antiguo *docga*, que originalmente se refería a un tipo específico de sabueso, el mastín. Esta especie era tan común en Inglaterra que su nombre finalmente se convirtió en la palabra general para perros (este proceso se llama [*metonimia*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonimia)):

> In 14th-century England, hound (from Old English hund) was the general word for all domestic canines, and dog referred to a subtype of hound, a group including the mastiff. It is believed this dog type was so common that it eventually became the prototype of the category "hound".<sup>[2](https://hrcak.srce.hr/index.php?show=clanak&id_clanak_jezik=48370&lang=en)</sup> By the 16th century, dog had become the general word, and hound had begun to refer only to dog types used for hunting.<sup>[3](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uZcs6poXkfEC&pg=PA215&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup> In the 16th century dog was also adopted by several continental European languages as their word for mastiff.<sup>[4](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dog)</sup>
>
> - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog#Etymology

Puede ser que algo similar ocurrió con *can* → *perro*, como ha pasado con [*cazón* → *tiburón*](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9563/4183).

---

**Notas:**

<sup>1. Todas las palabras antiguas viene últimamente del PIE [**kwon-*](https://www.omniglot.com/blog/?p=4329)</sup>
<sup>2. En la mayoría de dialectos (salvo unos de los baleares):</sup>

> <sup>És un mot que ha desaparegut quasi completament del llenguatge viu de Catalunya i València, substituït per son sinònim *gos*; a les Balears sí que es conserva amb tot el seu poder. [dcvb - *ca*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=ca&Id=27981&search=ca)</sup>

<sup>3. Considera estas variantes en las otras lenguas románicas:</sup>

> <sup>**Etim.:** probablement de *kos* o *kus*, onomatopeia de la veu amb què es sol cridar el ca, i que té variants en totes les llengües romàniques (cf. esp. *gozque*, ant. fr. *gous*, port. *gozo*, it. *cuccio*, etc.). [dcvb - *gos*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=gos&Id=77824&search=gos)</sup>

Comment: En catalán hay zonas donde aún se dice _ca_ ([referencia](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=ca&Id=27981&search=ca)).

Comment: Dijiste en otra pregunta que fuera por tabúes. Me gustaría saber más sobre eso.